# Using groupBy in angular repeater

Tags: json, angularjs

I have some JSON which I display in an angular repeater. I need to group the results in the repeater and I groupBy doesn't seem to work

Using this JSON...

```
{  
"Products":[  
  {  
     "Code":"ELA-67",
     "Site":"SITE1",
     "Attributes":{  
        "Term":"36",
        "quantity":1
     }
  },
  {  
     "Code":"ELI-45",
     "Site":"SITE2",
     "Attributes":{  
        "Term":"36",
        "quantity":1
     }
  },
  {  
     "Code":"COA-56",
     "Site":"SITE1",
     "Attributes":{  
        "Term":"36",
        "quantity":1
     }
  },
  {  
     "Code":"COY-67",
     "Site":"SITE2",
     "Attributes":{  
        "Term":"36",
        "quantity":1
     }
  }
```

]
}

I want to create this layout

SITE1

- ELA-67
- COA-56

SITE2

- ELI-45
- COY-67

I was trying to use the groupBy function...

```
<div ng-repeat="Products in productAttributes.Products | groupBy: 'Products.Code'>
Product name: {{Products.Code}}
Site location: {{Products.Site}}
</div>
```

but I was getting an error below...

Error: error:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider

Any ideas?

Comment: angular does not have `groupBy` filter, only this [`currency,date,filter,json,limitTo,lowercase,number,orderBy,uppercase`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) filters by default. Are you wrote own function or use some third-party libs?

Comment: You are right - I was missing the lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you need to group the products by `Site` and not by `Code` :

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['angular.filter']);

demoApp.controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.productAttributes = {
        "Products": [{
            "Code": "ELA-67",
                "Site": "SITE1",
                "Attributes": {
                "Term": "36",
                    "quantity": 1
            }
        }, {
            "Code": "ELI-45",
                "Site": "SITE2",
                "Attributes": {
                "Term": "36",
                    "quantity": 1
            }
        }, {
            "Code": "COA-56",
                "Site": "SITE1",
                "Attributes": {
                "Term": "36",
                    "quantity": 1
            }
        }, {
            "Code": "COY-67",
                "Site": "SITE2",
                "Attributes": {
                "Term": "36",
                    "quantity": 1
            }
        }]
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in productAttributes.Products | groupBy: 'Site'">{{ key }}
        <li ng-repeat="site in value">{{site.Code}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to include the 'angular-filter' module as a dependency in your module declaration, like this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

See the [Getting Started](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#get-started) section of the angular-filter module for more info.

Comment: @Puce In order to make things light weight. You just include all the things you need that way.